# 2 columns within a table css

Tags: html, css

Hi I inherited a JavaScript application with a search window containing the following code.

I would like text "Statistics Search" to appear above the Statistics label and check box. Then, to the right of this I would like the other 3 rows to appear one on top of the other with "Estimates Search" at the top. Is this possible to do with the current table pTable? I do not want to remove the table because it links to many other files.

I tried adding a new div of width 50% but that did now work. Thank you for any help.

CSS

```
.pPane {
    float: right;
    clear: right;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
.ptable
{
    float:left;
    margin-top:10px;
}
.pBottom 
{
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="pPane" class="pPane">
    <div id="pBottom" class="pBottom">
        <table id="pTable" class="ptable">
            <tr><td colspan="9"><span id="sSearch" style="color:black; font-size:12px; text-decoration:underline;">Statistics Search 
                          </span></td></tr>
            <tr><td colspan="9"><label>Statistics</label></td><td><input id="1" type="checkbox" /></td></tr>
            <tr><td colspan="9"><span id="eSearch" style="color:black; font-size:12px; text-decoration:underline;">Estimates Search</span></td></tr>
            <tr><td colspan="9"><label>Estimate 1</label></td><td><input id="2" type="checkbox" /></td></tr>
            <tr><td colspan="9"><label>Estimate 2</label></td><td><input id="3" type="checkbox" /></td></tr>
            <tr><td colspan="9"><label>Estimate 3</label></td><td><input id="4" type="checkbox" /></td></tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't see the phrase "Statistics Search" anywhere in your code sample.

Comment: can you add result table, that you want to make?

Comment: Sorry, I added it now. I didn't know if it would help since I may have not been formatting it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/GHC7T/3/

I think you could do better with Divs and CSS but this is quick. Using tables like this is not best practice.

```
<div id="pPane" class="pPane">
<div id="pBottom" class="pBottom">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table id="pTable" class="ptable">
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="9">
                            <span id="sSearch" style="color:black; font-size:12px; text-decoration:underline;">
                                Statistics Search
                            </span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr><td colspan="9"><label>Statistics</label></td><td><input id="1" type="checkbox" /></td></tr>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td>

                <table>


                    <tr><td colspan="9"><span id="eSearch" style="color:black; font-size:12px; text-decoration:underline;">Estimates Search</span></td></tr>
                    <tr><td colspan="9"><label>Estimate 1</label></td><td><input id="2" type="checkbox" /></td></tr>
                    <tr><td colspan="9"><label>Estimate 2</label></td><td><input id="3" type="checkbox" /></td></tr>
                    <tr><td colspan="9"><label>Estimate 3</label></td><td><input id="4" type="checkbox" /></td></tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Or you could try this http://jsfiddle.net/LDJ2X/3/

```
<div id="pPane" class="pPane">
<div id="pBottom" class="pBottom">
    <table id="pTable" class="ptable">
        <tr>
            <td>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <span id="sSearch" style="color:black; font-size:12px; text-decoration:underline;">
                    Statistics Search
                </span>
            </td>
            <td colspan="2"><span id="eSearch" style="color:black; font-size:12px; text-decoration:underline;">Estimates Search</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr rowspan="3">
            <td>
                <label>Statistics</label>
            </td>
            <td><input id="1" type="checkbox" /></td>
            <td><label>Estimate 1</label></td>
            <td><input id="2" type="checkbox" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" />
            <td><label>Estimate 2</label></td>
            <td><input id="3" type="checkbox" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td colspan="2" /><td><label>Estimate 3</label></td><td><input id="4" type="checkbox" /></td></tr>
        </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Added a valign top and removed the colspans (because really, they do nothing for you here) http://jsfiddle.net/GHC7T/4/ couldn't help myself

Comment: Yes sorry copy and paste, the enemy of the developer.

Comment: Thanks. This displays how I want it to display, but is it possible the Estimate code could be inside the pTable code with that being the only table? I'm not sure the Search will work with this setup but i will try it out. Thanks!

Comment: @ThomasHarris Is there a way to increase the amount of space between the columns? Thank you.